# Django "Page not found (404)"

Tags: python, django

I think I done everything correct but I don't know why it doesn't work. When I try to reach a page I get error "Page not found (404)".

So, this all products page works 127.0.0.1:8000/products/ but when I try to visit single product page 127.0.0.1:8000/products/audi I get error that it's not found...

So, maybe you what's wrong here?
Thank you.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://link/products/audi
Using the URLconf defined in ecommerce.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
^admin/doc/
^admin/
^products/ ^$ [name='products']
^products/ ^$(?P<slug>.*)/$
^contact/ [name='contact_us']
The current URL, products/audi, didn't match any of these.
```

Main project urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT
        }),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        }),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^products/', include('products.urls')),
    url(r'^contact/', 'contact.views.contact_us', name='contact_us'),
)
```

Products app urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url


urlpatterns = patterns('products.views',
    url(r'^$', 'all_products', name='products'),
    url(r'^$(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'single_product'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext, get_object_or_404

from .models import Product

def all_products(request):
    products = Product.objects.filter(active=True)
    return render_to_response('products/all.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def single_product(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('products/single.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title',]


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images/')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL pattern has an extra `$` at the beginning, so it can never match anything:

```
url(r'^$(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'single_product')
```

This should be:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'single_product')
```

This still requires a trailing slash, which is the normal pattern. With that corrected, your URL should be `/products/audi/`. You don't show the context in which that URL is created, but this is one example of why it's a good idea to use Django's [url reversal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) to build URLs if at all possible. That would look something like this, in Python code (for instance, possibly in a `get_absolute_url` method on the model:

```
reverse('single_product', kwargs={'slug': someproduct.slug})
```

Or like this, in a template:

Django 1.5:

```
{% url 'single_product' someproduct.slug %}
```

Django 1.4 and earlier:

```
{% url single_product someproduct.slug %}
```

Comment: A traling slash doesn't help.

Comment: Oh, wait, you also have a bogus `$` at the beginning of your pattern. Fix that.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
url(r'^$(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'single_product'),
```

Note this `$` just after `^`, in regexp it states for a string end. Replace with

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'single_product'),
```